# Customize tm_compass() background

Tags: r, maps, tmap, dismo

In the code below, how do I set background color and transparency for`tm_compass()`as I can do for map title?

```
library(tmap)
library(dismo)

ny.map <- gmap(x = "New York", zoom = 13, type = "satellite")

print(tm_shape(shp = ny.map) +
      tm_raster() +
      tm_compass(position = c("right", "top"),
                 type = "4star",
                 show.labels = 2) +
      tm_layout(title = "New York",
                title.bg.color = "white",
                title.bg.alpha = 0.5))
```

[image] 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing the CRAN manual, I thought it would not be possible to do the job. My workaround was to manually create a polygon that covers the compass. This is a tedious work, but this is perhaps the way to go right now. The first step is to create a polygon. `extent()` gives you min and max for longitude and latitude. I used xmax and ymax to specify five points for a polygon. (I played with values and found the optimal values.) We need to assign a right projection to the polygon. If you type `ny.map` in your R Console, you will see `coord. ref.`. This is the projection you need. Then, I added the polygon to the map using `tm_shape()` and `tm_fill()`.

```
lon <- c(extent(ny.map)[2]-2100, extent(ny.map)[2]-250, extent(ny.map)[2]-250, extent(ny.map)[2]-2100, extent(ny.map)[2]-2100)
lat <- c(extent(ny.map)[4]-250, extent(ny.map)[4]-250, extent(ny.map)[4]-2100, extent(ny.map)[4]-2100,extent(ny.map)[4]-250)

foo <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(lon, lat))), ID = 1)),
                   proj4string = CRS("+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs"))

tm_shape(shp = ny.map) +
tm_raster() +
tm_shape(shp = foo) +
tm_fill("red", alpha = 0.4) +
tm_compass(position = c("right", "top"),
           type = "4star",
           show.labels = 2) +
tm_layout(title = "New York",
          title.bg.color = "white",
          title.bg.alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: I too couldn't find a way to do this easily; for example,`tm_text()`takes arguments`bg.color`and`bg.alpha`and wish`tm_compass()`had something similar. Your method works for the time being. Thanks.

Comment: @Manojit I see. Let's hope there will be an update in the package. If your case is done, please click the green tick below the voting triangles. In this way, future SO reader will know that the solution is working.

Answer (score 1):

Customizing `tm_compass()` (and `tm_scale_bar()`) background is supported starting from **tmap** version 3.1:

```r
library(spData)
library(tmap)

tm_shape(elev) +
  tm_raster() + 
  tm_compass(bg.color = "white", 
             bg.alpha = 0.7,
             type = "8star",
             position = c("left", "bottom"),
             size = 3) +
  tm_layout(legend.show = FALSE)
```

[image]